# Call post_save after many to many fields are saved in database

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

I have model

```
class UserPermission(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_type = models.ManyToManyField(UserType)
    persona = models.ManyToManyField(Persona)
```

And post save signal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=UserPermission)
def post_save_user_permissions(sender, instance, **kwargs)
    """
    Depending on selected UserType and Persona for a user, Update some other model
    """
    pass
```

I want all updated values of both the m2m fields in post save signal. but issue here is post save signal is getting called before m2m fields saved into db.

I could have used m2m_changed signal, but there are two m2m fields and I can't associate or link these two signals

Is there anyway to call post_save once all m2m fields in model are saved into db.

Comment: If you ever found a way around this, could you post an answer?

Comment: Anyone coming across this: Check out the on_commit method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- try post_save on `UserType`
- try to name the in-between table using [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/), like `through='UserPermissionType'` and try post_save on `UserPermissionType`

I hope I gave you enough clues to find the solution.

Comment: Yes, if there was only one m2m field, but I have two m2m fields in UserPermission model. I want to do something after these m2m fields are saved in database.